# Getting nsi:type in xml

Tags: c#, xml

So I have a XML File that looks like this

```
<MyObjectBuilder_Sector xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SectorObjects>
    <MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_CubeGrid">
      <EntityId>-8358349049537298307</EntityId>
      <LinearVelocity x="0" y="0" z="0" />
    </MyObjectBuilder>
  </SectorObjects>
</MyObjectBuilder_Sector>
```

I was curious how in C# how I could retrieve that **MyObjectBuilder_CubeGrid** from the MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase node. The best i got is this

```
fileLoc = ofd.FileName;
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(fileLoc);
XmlNode typeOfNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("MyObjectBuilder_Sector/SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase").ToString();
```

Which of course just gets me the node not the xsi:type of the node. I've looked all over for it and can not find an answer.

-Cheers
     Jacob Bender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access node's attribute this way :

```
XmlNode typeOfNode = 
    xdoc.SelectSingleNode("MyObjectBuilder_Sector/SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase");

//here typeValue variable will contains "MyObjectBuilder_CubeGrid"
String typeValue = typeOfNode.Attributes["xsi:type"].Value;
```